# AAR dependency is obfuscated in spite of available proguard.txt forbidding an obfuscation

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, aar

We have an artifact compiled as AAR and stored in Maven repository.
Our artifact can be added as dependency

```
compile ('com.ourcompany:sdk:2.1.16@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

We have following settings in *build.gradle* script.

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

   defaultConfig {
       ...
       consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}
```

File *proguard-rules.pro* contains following rules

```
# Common
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

# attributes
-keepattributes InnerClasses, Signature, *Annotation*, Exceptions

# java
-dontwarn javax.naming.**
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Files
-dontwarn java.nio.file.Path
-dontwarn java.nio.file.OpenOption
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# retrofit
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# gson
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# otto
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

# google play services
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# support
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

We're trying to add library as a dependency to an app which contains in *build.gradle* following settings

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       ...
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile ('com.ourcompany:sdk:2.1.16@aar') {
      transitive = true
   }
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
}
```

We've checked that *proguard.txt* exists within our AAR artifact.
We've tested this integration in two environments:

Android Studio 1.5.1 ends up build process with following result:
First build:

```
    :app:proguardDebug
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find superclass or interface rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:retrofit.RestMethodInfo$RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
Warning:retrofit.RxSupport$2: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
Warning:retrofit.android.AndroidApacheClient: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(org.apache.http.Header)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void setEntity(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericEntityHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(org.apache.http.Header)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$GenericHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity: can't find referenced method 'void setContentType(java.lang.String)' in program class retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity
Warning:retrofit.client.ApacheClient$TypedOutputEntity: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:there were 148 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Exception while processing task 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:app:dexDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Unable to compute hash of D:\Workspace\AppAndroid\TestApp\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\debug\classes.jar
```

Second build, just:

```
:app:packageDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Unable to compute hash of D:\Workspace\AppAndroid\TestApp\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\debug\classes.jar
```

Android Studio 1.4.2

Build complete successfully but in runtime we're getting NullPointerException which caused by code obfuscation.

We also tried to build the project via *gradlew :app:clean :app:assembleDebug*
and ended up with

```
':app:proguardDebug', task ':app:dexDebug', task ':app:validateDebugSigning', task ':app:packageDebug', task ':app:zipalignDebug', task ':app:assembleDebug']
    22:15:56.077 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:clean (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
    22:15:56.077 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:clean
    22:15:56.097 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:clean'
    22:15:56.097 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:clean' is up-to-date
    22:15:56.098 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':app:clean' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
      Task has not declared any outputs.
    22:15:56.098 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':app:clean'.
    22:15:56.099 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DeleteActionImpl] Deleting D:\Workspace\AppAndroid\TestApp\app\build
    22:15:56.933 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:clean'
    22:15:56.934 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:clean FAILED
    22:15:56.957 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:clean (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.88 secs.
    22:15:56.957 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.88 secs, idle: 0.001 secs
    22:15:56.977 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    22:15:56.977 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
    22:15:56.977 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    22:15:56.977 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 7.678 secs
    22:15:57.003 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
    22:15:57.003 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
    22:15:57.005 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for settings file 'D:\Workspace\AppAndroid\TestApp\settings.gradle'
```

Your help is really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cleared all caches, recreated project from scratch and now it works fine.

Comment: usually you are not allowed to do this :)